# "Emulating" std::declval issues. Works (kind of) in g++, fails to compile in clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Trying to better understand [std::declval](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval), I came up with the following "toy model" code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Bar
{
    Bar(double);  // some non-default ctor
    double f();   // some function of which return type we want to get
};

using Barref = Bar&&; // emulating std::declval<Bar>()

int main()
{
    // FUNKY, compiles in g++, not in clang++
    // error: unexpected type name 'Barref': expected expression
    decltype(Barref.f()) x; // (1)
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl; // i -> int INCORRECT

    // OK, just for testing
    decltype(std::declval<Bar>().f()) y; // (2)
    std::cout << typeid(y).name() << std::endl; // d -> double CORRECT
}
```

So I'm typedef-ing `Barref` as a rvalue reference of type `Bar&&`, and use it in an a `decltype` expression in (1). If I understand correctly, this is exactly what `std::declval` does, it is a non-defined function that returns a rvalue reference to its template parameter

```
template<class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();
```

so we can then use the latter in unevaluated contexts, such as `decltype`. It is useful whenever the type has a non-default ctor, and we'd like to get some type information about some member function without the need to construct the object. Well, that's what I though my code below does. g++5.1 [compiles it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/w2ytZaOhyqwveINQ), but `x` is of type `int` (instead of `double`, as I would have guessed). However, `clang++` [fails to compile the code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RjyclwLg7dsT6NRH), saying

> error: unexpected type name 'Barref': expected expression
>       decltype(Barref.f()) x;

**My question(s):**

1. Is the code above legal? Is my usage of `decltype(Barref.f())` really the same as using `decltype(std::declval<Bar>().f())`? It seems a bit weird, as `Barref.f()` is not really a return value of a function (even if un-evaluated). I realized that even `decltype(Bar.f())` compiles (g++), with no type alias whatsoever.
2. If the code is legal, why does the type of `x` is `int` instead of `double`?

Comment: `Barref` is a type (well, an alias for a type). `std::declval<Bar>()` is an expression. Obvious GCC bug.

Comment: @T.C. I thought the same thing, so the code shouldn't compile. I realized now that even something like `decltype(Bar.something()) x;` compiles, even if `something` is not even a member of `Bar`. Have no idea why g++ compiles it, and decltype as `int`. Very weird.

Comment: Reported as [bug 66548](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66548)

Comment: @T.C. you were fast :) Thanks, I didn't even think trying gcc49, which indeed fails.

Comment: Emulating `declval` would be declaring `Bar&& Barref();` and then using `decltype(Barref().f()) x;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimized to

```
struct Meow {};

int main(){
    decltype(Meow.purr()) d;
}
```

This is plainly invalid code, yet GCC 5.1 and trunk accept it. Not much to say about it other than "bug". Interestingly, both correctly rejects

```
struct Meow {};
decltype(Meow.purr()) d;
```

Comment: Weirdly after that invalid line you can write a bunch of [nonsense](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9LDH8WdrejxzSzLd).

Comment: @0x499602D2 oh wow, this seems to be even more interesting ;) But as I said, `d` is declared as `int`, so I guess it's a mystery why. I first thought that the lines are non-sense non-sense, i.e. not even parseable.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well, if you accept that `decltype(Meow.purr())` is `int` (by the buggy GCC logic) then the later lines won't be nonsense.